# Where can I find the official documentation for what can be included in a Gemfile?

Tags: bundler

I know that [gembundler.com](http://gembundler.com/) has a lot of useful examples and such for how to use bundler, but where can I find the full documentation on what options are available to be used in a Gemfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you near the bottom of [gembundler.com's homepage](http://gembundler.com/#learn-about) you'll see that there's a link there to bundler's man pages. The [Gemfile(5)](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html) page there has a complete list of options and such that you can use in your Gemfile.